# Wordpress importing database - CREATE command denied to user

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to upload a WordPress database from local to hosting site. First, I solved the issue by replacing `utf8mb4` with `utf8` as you can view the error at [this link](http://take.ms/MoWG1T).

**Now I am getting the following issue:**

```
Error
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `blogpost`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

 `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
 `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'blogsit_admin'@'localhost' for table 'wp_commentmeta'
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need a MySQL user with more privileges..

Comment: i did't understand what you are talking about?

Comment: The error `CREATE command denied to user 'blogsit_admin'...` states that theMySQL user `blogsit_admin` does not have enough permission to create a table.

Comment: thank you. you solved it